# Como configurar a segurança para servidores dedicados e VPS?

Tags: php, linux, apache, segurança

Estou tendo problemas com as configurações de segurança de servidores virtualizados (VPS) e dedicados.

O que preciso fazer para proteger meu servidor Linux, com Apache, contra as principais ameaças de segurança, como rootkits, exploração de portas comuns abertas, *logging* de ações de root, etc? O que precisa ser instalado e configurado?

Comment: Caso a sua intenção seja compartilhar algo que possa ajudar o pessoal, sugiro coloque a parte da explicação como resposta. E a parte da pergunta vc coloca como se fosse alguem perguntando: ex.: 'quais as praticas comuns de segurança em VPS/Dedicados?'

Comment: Sim a intenção é compartilhar conhecimento. Tive problemas de segurança, e isso me ajudou muito. Então quero ajudar outros tambem.

Comment: Editei meu comentário @Tiago

Comment: @williamhk2 boa, vou mudar.

Comment: Beleza, ai também outras pessoas com outras dicas, podem responder como complementação à sua resposta! ;)

Comment: @gmsantos, RicardoHenrique, Rray, BrunoAugusto, JorgeB, Seria interessante vocês lerem com atenção antes. Quiz contribuir com conhecimento e não estava fazendo uma pergunta, basta ler a mensagem logo abaixo. Chato isso...

Comment: @Tiago abri uma questão no meta para discutirmos essa pergunta. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4048/essa-pergunta-pode-ser-reaberta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Via SSH - acesso Shell**

## Instale o ELS

```
wget --output-document=installer.sh http://servermonkeys.com/projects/els/installer.sh; chmod +x installer.sh; sh installer.sh; els --update; els --chkrootkit; els --rkhunter; els --chmodfiles; els --disabletelnet; els --hardensysctl; els --libsafe; els --mytop; els ---securepartitions
```

O ELS "Easy Linux Security" é um instalador de módulos e pequenos scripts de segurança atualizados. Existem muitos módulos disponíveis, vc pode lista-los executando simplesmente o comando els em seu shell. O que instalo acima são os que fazem mais diferença em termos de segurança do servidor: chkrootkit (rootkit), rkhunter (outro rootkit melhor ainda), chmodfiles (ele muda as permissões de acesso e execução de alguns scripts/comandos no servidor para apenas o root executa-los), disabletelnet (desabilita/desliga o telnet, deixando apenas o SSH), hardensysctl (faz um tunnig de sua interface de rede), instala o libsafe (apenas para sistemas 32 bits), mytop (instala um visualizador de processos mysql como o comando TOP faz com o sistema).

## Instale o logview

```
wget http://www.logview.org/logview-install
```

## Instale o CMM

```
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/cmm.tgz; tar -xzf cmm.tgz; cd cmm; ./install.sh
```

É um visualizador de logs via navegador, vc não precisa abrir o SSH para ver os logs intrincados do sistema, com este addon do WHM vc os vê via seu painel WHM.

## Instale o CMQ

```
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/cmq.tgz; tar -xzf cmq.tgz; cd cmq; ./install.sh
```

## Instale o CMC

```
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/cmc.tgz; tar -xzf cmc.tgz; cd cmc; ./install.sh
```

## Configurando a porta do SSH

```
pico -w /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

E mude a linha "Port 22" para a porta que vc deseja (lembre-se de adicionar a porta em seu firewall ANTES ou vc não conseguirá acessar mais o servidor).

## Aviso de acesso ROOT

Edite ".bash_profile" o com o comando:

```
cd root; pico -w /root/.bash_profile
```

Adicione o código abaixo no final do ultimo comando:

```
#
# GRAVA LOG E HISTORICO DE ACESSOS ROOT
#
echo `who` >> .access
#
# EMAIL DE AVISO ACESSO ROOT
#
rootalert() {
  echo 'ALERTA - Acesso ROOT SHELL'
  echo
  echo 'Servidor: '`hostname`
  echo 'Data: '`date`
  echo 'Usuario: '`who | awk '{ print $1 }'`
  echo 'TTY: '`who | awk '{ print $2 }'`
  echo 'Origem: '`who | awk '{ print $6 }' | /bin/cut -d '(' -f 2 | /bin/cut -d ')' -f 1`
  echo
  echo 'ACESSO ROOT EXECUTADO.'
  echo
  echo 'Estes usuários estão ativos neste instante como root:'
  echo `who | awk '{print $6}'`
  echo
  echo 'Últimos 10 acessos efetuados:'
  echo `last -n 10`
  echo
  echo 'Informações: Horário deste acesso, Uptime e Load Averange atual'
  echo `uptime`
  echo
}
rootalert | mail -s "Alerta: Acesso ROOT [`hostname`]" SEUEMAILAQUICARAMBA
```

## Instale o CSF Firewall

```
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/csf.tgz; tar -xzf csf.tgz; cd csf; sh install.sh
```

## Remova o Lynx

Primeiro identifique o pacote que vc tem instalado:

```
rpm -qa | grep lynx
```

Depois execute:

```
rpm -e lynx NOMEDOPACOTE
```

## Instalando e configurado corretamente o Maldetec

```
wget http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz ; tar -xzf maldetect-current.tar.gz ; cd maldetect-* ; sh ./install.sh ; maldet --update-ver ; maldet --update
```

Agora configurando, edite o arquivo "conf.maldet" em /usr/local/maldetect, editando a linha "email_alert=0" para "email_alert=1" e a linha "email_addr=" colocando o seu email que receberá o relatório.

Você pode executar ele na linha de comando especifica, por exemplo:

> maldet -a /home/USUARIO/
>
> maldet -a /home?/?/public_html

Aqui vai uma dica um tanto que radical: Vc pode configurar o maldetec para ele tentar limpar possíveis trojans ou códigos maliciosos que "colam" em códigos PHP intregos, e caso não consiga ele move o script/arquivo todo para o diretório /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/. Para isso edite a linha "quar_hits=0" para 'quar_hits=1" e "quar_clean=0" para "quar_clean=1".

## Usando o KSPLICE

```
wget -N https://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/install-uptrack; sh install-uptrack 8c7fea7e7e4e244d9ad4abacd55caf67fbed1d7f46ad31d1f3edea0eb61d8b7b --autoinstall
```

Distribuições que funciona http://ksplice.oracle.com/legacy#installing-uptrack?wi=1

Creditos: Alexandre Duran.